# jquery ajax request to nodejs server only works on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am quite new to AJAX and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a webpage that fetches all comments on a post with an AJAX get request. The issue is that the AJAX request is only successful after the webpage is refreshed. I disabled the cache to see if that would solve the issue, but it didn't.

For example, when I fetch the first comments after refreshing the page from post A and then go onto post B on the website, the comments from the post A appear as the comments for post B, then when I refresh the page the comments for post B are replaced with post B's comments successfully.

I am using jQuery to make the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: someURL,
    success: (comments) => {
        console.log(comments);
    
        comments.questions.forEach(questionComment => {
            $('.questionComments').append(
                `<div class="comment">
                    <p>${questionComment.content}</p>
                </div>
                `
            )
        });
    
    
        comments.answers.forEach(answer => {
            answer.forEach(answerComment => {
                $(`.answer#${answerComment.forId} .answerComments`).append(
                    `<div class="comment">
                    <p>${answerComment.content}</p>
                </div>
                `
                )
            })
        })
    },
    cache: false
})
```

**Server-Side:** (express.js, mongoose)

```
let allComments = {}
app.get('/questions/:questionID/getComments', (req, res) => {

       if (err) return console.error(err)

    Comment.find({ forQuestion: true, forId: req.params.questionID }, (err, questionComments) => {
        allComments['questions'] = questionComments 
    })


    Answer.find({ questionId: req.params.questionID }, (err, answers) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        allAnswerComments = []
        answers.forEach(answer => {
            Comment.find({ forAnswer: true, forId: answer._id }, (err, comments) => {
                allAnswerComments.push(comments)
            })
        });

        allComments['answers'] = allAnswerComments

    })

    res.send(allComments)

})
```

What the commets object looks like before the reload - a blank object[image: blank object]

What the comments object looks like after the reload[image]

When you navigate to a different post / different URL, the object from the previous post / URL is the initial object on the new post, and then when you reload the page the correct object is fetched.

Comment: Surely you wrote this in some special context, like a function or something. That's not enough code to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas Do you need more code?

Comment: @JeremyThille Do you need more code?

Comment: well it seems like you are setting all them to all the `.questionComments` on the page `$('.questionComments').append(` unlike the other one where you use an id....

Comment: Yes but I meant the code around the ajax call (which seems to work), not inside. Under what circumstances is this ajax call triggered?

Comment: @JeremyThille the ajax call is just a script tag on the webpage and gets triggered just before the `body` closing tag

Comment: @epascarello that is not the issue

Comment: Well it is impossible for us to guess with what is provided.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for trying to help, I am not sure what more data you need?

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but try adding: `cache:false` to the parameters in the ajax call. I don't think this is the problem as the URL should be different, but at least it will eliminate caching as a problem.

Comment: If you trigger this ajax call once, before the end of the body, then it's doing exactly hat it's supposed to do : trigger once, on page load. There's nothing surprising with that. If you want to refresh your comments/content, of yourse you have to trigger it a second time.

Comment: @imvain2 I already tried that, see code in question

Comment: @JeremyThille I understand, but the ajax request 'remembers' the previous data from the previous request and doesn't even fetch the correct comments on the original page load

Comment: could you please show the view of your webpage for better understanding of you point

Comment: How you navigate to different posts on page? Do you have any click event to load new post or can you share the more code for your front end?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, the AJAX request works when executed, but the problem is that it's executed only once, at page load. Let's write a function for this purpose:

```
function sendAJAX() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: someURL,
    success: (comments) => {
        console.log(comments);
    
        comments.questions.forEach(questionComment => {
            $('.questionComments').append(
                `<div class="comment">
                    <p>${questionComment.content}</p>
                </div>
                `
            )
        });
    
    
        comments.answers.forEach(answer => {
            answer.forEach(answerComment => {
                $(`.answer#${answerComment.forId} .answerComments`).append(
                    `<div class="comment">
                    <p>${answerComment.content}</p>
                </div>
                `
                )
            })
        })
    },
    cache: false
})
}
```

And ensure that it's called periodically:

```
sendAJAX();
seInterval(sendAJAX, 10000);
```

This will still be incorrect, because it will add all comments every ten seconds. To improve this, you could add a value representing the moment of the last request and on server-side load only the comments that were created between that moment and the current one.

Comment: Firstly, won't the `setTimeout` function run only once after 10 seconds, it is not a continual loop? Secondly, just to clarify, my AJAX response only receives the data after a reload/refresh, therefore putting the function into a timeout doesn't solve the issue. I tested it.

Comment: @koder613 I've meant setInterval. Please test again and wait for at least a minute while doing so.

Comment: I retested using `setInterval`. Now, the first AJAX call returns an empty object (after 10s) and the second AJAX call contains the correct data (after 20s). This happened after I restarted the nodejs server. Then when I went to a different post, after 10s the AJAX response from the previous post displayed and after 20s the correct response was displayed. So the issue hasn't been solved, nothing has changed. Thanks for your help

Comment: @koder613 I have edited my answer to ensure that it sends a request upon page load as well.

Comment: @koder613 My answer was written with the assumption that the server-side of your work behaves properly. If not, then you might want to ask a different question. You will need to look into the Network tab of your browser's Dev Tools. If every 10 seconds a request is being sent, then at least the sending part works. You might want to check the answers of your server in the Network tab for each requests you are sending to see whether there are errors.

Comment: So I think you are right, there must be an issue server-side, because one AJAX request returns nothing, only the second AJAX request returns data. In the network tab, the request is getting sent every 10 seconds as it should though

Comment: @koder613 Maybe we need to talk a little bit about the server-side. Whether there are errors thrown, what code is handling the requests and what do you see in the logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222918/discussion-between-koder613-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please describe your working on get parameters how are you setting it.Is there any cookie involved there? Telling the get comment will definitely help us to figure our the problem how ever sendAjax() function will be great idea instead of writing ajax in open Script.
On other side I will never recommend you seInterval(sendAJAX, 10000); instead install a service worker and hit it back from your API when new comment is added. And then it should only fetch the last one and put it in your comment section.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description it seems that the main problem is comment of Post A are appearing in comment of Post B.

Now, there is minimal data provided and by looking and your code, I am assuming that you are not refreshing page programmatically when switching from Post A to Post B.

So, the root cause of your problem is **append**. You are appending data to your div's. So, before your foreach loops, first clear the html using

```js
$('.questionComments').html("")
```

And for the answers replace it as below

```js
comments.answers.forEach(answer => {
        let first = true;
            answer.forEach(answerComment => {
            if(first) {
              $(`.answer#${answerComment.forId} .answerComments`).html("")
              first = false;
            }
            
                $(`.answer#${answerComment.forId} .answerComments`).append(
                    `<div class="comment">
                    <p>${answerComment.content}</p>
                </div>
                `
                )
            })
        })
```

The above snippet is just to demonstrate that you have to identify when the first comment is added and then reset it.

I haven't tested the snippet but I hope you got an idea what is wrong in the code.